# C# best way to store image in sqlite

Tags: c#, image, sqlite

I'm trying to build up a very simple database where i should have an entity composed by an image and a word associated with that.
I'm using SQLite with C# and since this would be an application which will evenutally be deployed I'd like to know if there's a best way to save an image in the database..

I saw a lot of techniques using stream of bytes, so my question is:

is better to save the stream of bytes in the field of the entity or is better to just save the path of the application where the image should be store?.. And why the chosen method should be better?..

thank

Answer (score 2):

It is better to save path in database and image(or other files) on hdd

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)